# Coded-UI-Tests: record button is disabled

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to create Coded-Ui tests for a WPF application, I'm following the msdn tutorial.

My problem: the "record" button is available, but disabled, so I'm not able to start recording.
Any idea?

My environment: Windows 10 / MSVS Entreprise 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was launching a Windows Store Coded UI and not a Windows Desktop one.
Problem fixed.